# how to compute power of a device

Tags: power, energy

how to compute power?, energy expended in joule?

the battery is 3.6V, the device has a voltage reference  which keeps voltage flowing through the circuit constant at 2.5 V, average current is 0.005 A for time period of 10 seconds.

Is it  power = 3.6V * 0.005A? or 2.5V *0.005A?
Energy = 3.6V * 0.005A * 10 seconds ? or 2.5V *0.005A* 10 seconds?

Note: i have no knowledge in electrical engineering.

Answer (score 3):

If the 3.6 volt battery is having 5mA taken from it then the power drain from that battery is 3.6V x 5mA = 18 mW. Over ten seconds this is 180mJ.

Comment: how can i convert the 18mW to Watt hour? i know 18mW/1000 is 0.018 watt. is it 0.018/(10 sec / 3600 sec)?

Comment: 1 watt second is 1 joule, that is 1 watt consumed for 1 second. If 1 watt was consumed for 1 hour that's 1 watt-hour.